# The program can't start because OCI.dll is missing

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I have an exe and which internally call the OCI functions to do Oracle database connection.

When I launch the exe, it always look for OCI.dll, if found it will open the application otherwise it will display the error message and it will not open. (The program can't start because OCI.dll is missing)

I want my application should run even if the oci.dll is not found, please let me know how i can do it programatically.